# SQL Sakila Query Question - Find all actors that have starred in films of all 16 film categories

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division, sakila-database

I am trying to put together a query from the Sakila database.

The query should find all actors that have starred in all 16 film categories.

To get all of this information into one table for querying, I have performed a INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name FROM actor a
INNER JOIN film_actor fa
ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
INNER JOIN film_category fc
ON fc.film_id = fa.film_id;
```

However, from there I do a GROUP BY on the category_id but don't know how to iterate through and count if a particular actor_id has all 16 categories?

Does this complex of a query require writing a FUNCTION or PROCEDURE?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Group against the actor name and check that the unique category count is 16:

```
SELECT a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM actor a
  INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
  INNER JOIN film_category fc ON fc.film_id = fa.film_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fc.category_id) = 
  ( 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) 
    FROM film_category
  )
```

Comment: Probably should add a `WHERE fc.category_id IN (...)` to limit the matches to the 16 categories desired, in case there are other categories added in the future.

Comment: @BillKarwin futureproofed the answer

Comment: Fair enough. It depends on whether the requirement is to check for a specific 16 categories, or to check that all categories are matched.

Comment: @BillKarwin "all 16 film categories" The content of the Sakila database has not changed since 2006 and is not likely to change in the future either.

Comment: @user2518312 remove the having and add COUNT(DISTINCT fc.category_id)  to what's selected, and you will see it only reports 3 in that case (so the having clause will filter out that row)

Comment: ello!  Thanks for the help!  That makes sense to me.  I also have in mind the case where you have 16 entries where actor_id = 1, film_id = a variety of numbers but category_id = 1,3, or 5 but not the other 16 categories?  In this case, would it require a procedure or function being written?  UPDATE: just looked over the query again and realized that HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fc.category_id) would automatically weed out this case described in this comment.  Thanks alot!!!!!